# Adding search icon to my search word on the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, search, icons, addition

Currently I'm practicing how to code by building a similar website and I got stuck with this step which's adding a search word together with the search icon just like in the shown image.

I did type the code for the word "Sök" which's in Swedish means "Search" but I'm curious how to add the icon so it looks the same.

[image: Search icon]

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const icon = document.querySelector('.icon');
    const search = document.querySelector('.search').value;

    function searchbar() {
      icon.style.display = "block";
      return
    }
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(9, 5, 31);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container .icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container .search {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <img class="icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/search--v1.png" />

    <input class="search" oninput="searchbar()" on type="text" placeholder="search">

  </div>
```

if you want to add the search icon next to the searched word just do this:
put the icon and the search bar inside the same parent and set position:absolute; to the icon and position: relative; to the parent that contains both the input and icon.

for the appearance of the search icon when typing:
just set display: none; to it, and use javascript when (input.value > 1) , the display of the icon will be (display: block;).

there are many ways to achieve that

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, could you help me out by typing the code for me. I don't really know how to do these steps.

Comment: Ok no problem I'll code one for you

Comment: i've created this one for you , now that you got the idea continue working on it